# Can bluetooth be used with iOS Multitasking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bluetooth

I'm thinking the answer to this is no, but does anyone know if a Bluetooth connection can be maintained in the background with iOS? I'm thinking I might be able to keep it around with the finite-task background API, but I haven't found anything indicating whether that's true or not. Another option would be to use GPS notifications and just reconnect every time the app gets a location changed notification.

Answer (score 0):

You a right. It's a NO.
But if you use location change notification to wake up your app, you may have a short period of time to use Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Bluetooth connection should be maintained, but if your bluetooth application is not the foreground application it will not receive any data / commands, when it becomes foreground it will.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, I use this trick to allow an App to use foreground APIs for iBeacons to allow the app to range even when the App is in the background.

To range for iBeacons it uses a high power API and as so this is restricted to only run when the App is in the foreground and stops all delegates being called once the App enters the background.

By playing a silent audio file and adding the AirPlay capability to your plist it allows your app to run in the background just as it would if it was in the foreground.

I'm not sure if it will work for your case but as iBeacons do use the Core Bluetooth and Core Location frameworks it might just do what you are asking.

http://yifan.lu/2013/12/17/unlimited-backgrounding-on-ios/

Note although this trick has not been patched by Apple in iOS8 beta 5 it is possible they will in an update.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iBeacons, there are built-in APIs for handling when you enter/exit a beacon region, and you typically get ~5 seconds to range for beacons at that point before the app is put to sleep. Theoretically, you could start a background task w/ expiration handler that might allow you to range for ~30 seconds while backgrounded, but I have not verified this is the case. I do know that the background task can be started when normal CLRegions are entered/exited while in the background, and there is functionally no difference between CLRegions and CLBeaconRegions in terms of region monitoring, so if I had to guess I would say this is more-than-likely possible.